# Spotfire- Configure Trellis

Tags: spotfire

Does anyone know if trellis panels can be configured or customized? I'm looking to move my "Post-Inspection" panel below my "Pre-Inspection" panel.

Thanks!

[Spotfire Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dOxj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was easier than expected. Select Data> Column Properties and select the desired column. Select the "Sort Order" tab below the column selection and apply a "Custom Sort Order". You can move values up/down the list as desired.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way, but it might not be to your liking:
[Trellis by rows picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DgEw.png)

In properties -> Trellis -> Rows (where the pink in the picture is): right click where it says "None" and choose custom expression.

The expression would look like this:

<[table name here].[column name here]="... Pre Inspection">

Spotfire will then trellis by 'True' and 'False': the values that are true will be above those that are false.
This means you will lose the titles of each trellis, however.

Hope this makes sense!

Comment: This was a great thought. I was able to maintain the titles by creating a case, but the pre still doesn't stack on top of the post.